# Multiple tabs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm using the following code for tabs, it works really nicely but I haven't figured out how to show multiple tab sets on the same page properly, would really appreciate it, if someone could give me a little help.

```
    $("ul.tabs li.label").hide();
$(".tab-set > div").hide();
$(".tab-set > div").eq(0).show();
$("ul.tabs a").click(
  function() {
      $("ul.tabs a.selected").removeClass('selected');
      $(".tab-set > div").hide();
      $(""+$(this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      return false;
  }
);
$("#toggle-label").click( function() {
  $(".tabs li.label").toggle();
  return false;
});
$("ul.tabs a[href="+location.hash+"]").click();
```

HTML:

```
<!-- tab group 1 -->
<div class="widget">
    <ul class="tabs"> 
        <li><a href="#1" class="selected">tab1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#2">tab2</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-set">
        <div id="1">
            tab1
        </div>
        <div id="2">
            tab2
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- tab group 2 -->
<div class="widget">
    <ul class="tabs"> 
        <li><a href="#3" class="selected">tab1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#4">tab2</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-set">
        <div id="3">
            tab1
        </div>
        <div id="4">
            tab2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: multiple tabs with javascript or multiple tabs with jquery

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but if you are already using jQuery, you could use jQuery UI tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/